# Is it really important to do axiomatic study of real numbers before learning Calculus?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, axioms

I am currently beginning with *Calculus Volume 1 by Tom M. Apostol* . It has an introduction chapter divided into 4 parts namely

- Historical introduction
- Basic concept of set theory
- A set of axioms for real number system
- Mathematical induction, summation notation and related Topics

I have read the the first two topics as the first one was interesting and the second one was pretty easy but then I encounter the third part which quite perplexed me.

I mean what was the need to write proofs for the basic properties of real numbers that we have been using for years since the starting of our school time ? And the proofs written themselves are very weird, mostly paragraphs of statements based on numerous axioms or theorems.

I am a bit in hurry or you may say impatient, as I know basic uses of Calculus (uses of formulas of Calculus to find slope, area etc and their applications) for about a year as it was in the syllabus of my 12th grade but they only taught us how to use the formulas to find answers of questions. They didn't told us the working of Calculus. They didn't give any intuition or proves. It kind of frustrated me and made me impatient to learn calculus in depth.

So I didn't try the exercises of this topic as it only contained questions asking for proofs of numerous statements.

**I am bit skeptic whether I should pay much attention to this topic and it's exercises on not ?
Is this topic really that important for in depth knowledge of Calculus ?**

Comment: As long as you have some basic proficiency in rigorous math, most people typically skip this stuff. Perhaps just skim through it and carry on.

Comment: @Vercingetorix Won't these be used in Proofs of formulas of Calculus that they taught me in school ?

Comment: It’s certainly not necessary. Most high school and college calculus here in the States doesn’t cover it. But it is something a person taking a sophisticated interest in math should learn. Apostle is definitely not meant for engineering students learning calculus, but for students seeking to learn the details.

Comment: I think it's important to know what the axioms are and what they imply. For rigorous calculus/analysis (at the level of Apostol), in particular, the completeness property (or equivalently, the least upper bound property) is essential. On the other hand, constructing the real numbers (proving the existence of a set that satisfies the axioms) is something best deferred until later IMO.

Comment: No, you don't need to develop calculus rigorously from the axioms for the real numbers in order to understand it clearly and use it effectively. Plenty of engineers and physicists use calculus without knowing how to provide rigorous proofs (but they understand how to derive the formulas, and why the results are intuitively plausible). In my opinion you should know how to derive or discover formulas like the product rule or the chain rule and you should understand intuitively why, say, the fundamental theorem of calculus is true. A clear intuitive understanding of calculus goes a long way.

Comment: @Bungo I have just read through it, but should I also attempt it's exercises ?

Comment: @user933496 What is your goal? Btw, this kind of discussion is better suited to chat instead of extended comments. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics I'll be happy to chat with you there if you like.

Comment: @Bungo To master Calculus ?

Comment: You should do I.3.5 exercise 10, I.3.12 exercises 1, 2 and 6. The rest you can skip solving. However, do read them all, because all are results that you will be using later.

Comment: Just curious, how did you choose this book for your self-learning? Because most calculus books don’t cover these things, but usually, Apostol is chosen specifically because it handles questions with mathematical rigor, and mathematical rigor is one of the things you are expected to learn from reading it. Did someone recommend the book to you?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I googled for best books for in depth knowledge of Calculus and got these two names M. Spivak and Tom M. Apostol. I came to know from reviews that Spivak is less based on application so to strike a balance, I chose to download Calculus by Apostol and then I read the first topic of this chapter which was very exciting so I purchased it and now I am here. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) three possible reasons to embark on an axiomatic development of anything:

1. Such that we can get *general* results that will transfer to different structures that satisfy the same axioms.
2. As a way to make establish a convention for what is a valid proof and what is just handwaving. That's important especially in an area where handwaving is known to often lead to false conclusions -- and the history of calculus contains some spectacular examples of smart, capable people being led astray because they didn't yet have solid concepts of what is and isn't a good proof.
3. Because the axiomatic approach is actually easier than to explain how the things we're speaking about work *internally*.

The first of these is supremely important in many areas of modern mathematics, but doesn't apply to the reals, full stop. There *are* no other models of the axioms that are usually presented (up to isomorphism, and as long as we stay within mainstream mathematical foundations, bla bla pedantry yada).

The second one is easy to make idealistic speeches about, and it certainly has something to go for it in a calculus course that will be most students' first encounter with the general level of proof and rigor in it. You can't demand rigorous proofs without first agreeing which facts you can prove things *from*.

The *third* one is one that applies *very rarely*. Usually it's a lot easier to understand a main example or two in at least some detail before moving on to an abstraction. However, the real numbers are arguably one of the few cases where the abstract axiomatic model is actually easier than being more concrete.

In particular, in calculus (and real analysis in general) we often find ourselves needing to prove that such-and-such sequence or function has a *limit*, according to the particular technical definition of limit. The fact that there *is* a number that satisfies the convolutions of definition is often *not* something that's really obvious based on grade-school experience with real-number *arithmetic*. Our choices are then basically:

1. Give a complex but complete definition of "what a real number really is", with all the internal details (using, for example, Dedekind cuts), and then prove that based on this definition the limits do indeed exist under such-and-such condition, or
2. Simply assert as an axiom that real numbers with certain properties (typically something like the existence of suprema) exist, and derive consequences from that.

The first way is, as I've noted, the way that *usually* works best. But in the particular case of the reals, the concrete definition we start with is going to look very *unmotivated* to students, and it certainly won't in any way evoke the concept they thought they knew from grade school. In fact, just the opposite: It's far from intuitive that *arithmetic* on Dedekind cuts works like we expect real arithmetic to work. So doing it the concrete way would actually function as a *barrier* to understanding.

On the other hand, the supremum property can count as a *mostly* intuitive fact about how the hand-wavy geometric concept of the real number line behaves. Simply asserting it will allow us move on relatively quickly to interesting *uses* of reals, while still providing the ingredients for having valid *proofs* that the limits we need to exist actually do exist.

Comment: So you meant say that before this system of proofs it was a bit chaotic to prove theorems as it was difficult to assign which proof is valid and which is not as different mathematicians gave different proofs which seemed logical or intuitive to them but that didn't work for others. So to come up with aggreement mathematicians developed this system where they said " Look regarding __ topic, we all agree that so and so statements are true and we call it axioms. Now if you wanna prove anything use these axioms or theorems based on them otherwise we won't accept it." Did I got that right ?

Answer (score 2):

Skip it if that's your preference. The only thing you'd be missing out on is an excellent opportunity to build your foundational knowledge, your mental muscle so to speak, particularly in rigor, techniques of proof, and the mathematical way of thinking. If you later get to things like real analysis, you might find some of these preliminaries useful when you search for counterexamples.